# RichFaces inputtext invoke fileupload

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I have an h:inputText and a rich:fileUpload. I'd like the inputText to, when click, invoke the fileUpload. How would I go about doing this? Right now, I have this:

```
<h:inputText id="uploadName" maxlength="255" value="#{bean.fileName}" required="false"
                                    onclick="INVOKE FILEUPLOAD"
                                    >
                                        </h:inputText>                                  
                                        <rich:fileUpload id="uploadFile" addControlLabel="Upload"
                                            fileUploadListener="#{bean.fileUploadListener}"
                                            uploadData="#{bean.data}"
                                            listWidth="100px" listHeight="0px" maxFilesQuantity="1"
                                            immediateUpload="true" acceptedTypes="xml" allowFlash="false"
                                            status="eventQueueFileUpload">

                                        </rich:fileUpload>
```

Essentially, I want the inputText and the fileUpload to have the same function, I would just show the filename in the inputText.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force a browser to trigger a file upload. What you *can* do is use CSS tricks to position the file input over the text input and make it transparent. Then it looks like you've got an input field (and note you don't really even need it to be a text input; it can just be a `<span>`, since you need the form to contain the parameter value from the file input itself anyway).

It's not super-hard to make this work for decent browsers, but it can be a minor pain for IE. IE7 lets people type into the file input, which you probably don't want. Everything else will launch the file browser dialog when the input is clicked anywhere.

Comment: How would I go about using a span for this? I'm pretty new to richfaces; How would I tie the fileupload to the span?

Comment: What I meant was that if you want to show the selected file name, you can just put it into an ordinary `<span>` tag; it doesn't have to be an `<input>`.  You'd show the filename in the `<span>` by handling the "change" event from the file input. Note that browsers will not give you the complete pathname, just the name of the file.

Comment: I need to to be an inputText, it's part of the design spec.

Comment: Well ok the, do whatever, but having it be a real text input is just going to make it harder; at least make it "readonly".

Comment: Yes, readyonly is fine. I just have to have it this specific way due to design specs.

Comment: Well then just position the readonly `<input>` under the file `<input>`.  The clicks will be handled by the `<file>` input.  One trick that might help with making sure all the clicks make it to the right element would be to also put a `<label>` in the same place, such that the `<label>` element is the same size as the file `<input>` (but otherwise empty).  Give the `<label>` a "for" attribute with the "id" of the file `<input>`.  (I'm not 100% sure that'll help, but it's something I've used for other similar purposes.)